# blob.text() returning buffer instead of string

Tags: http, blob, fs

I am receiving a blob from an HTTP call, and want to convert the blob to text.

The blob has a size and a type (in this case application/json), but when I call blob.text() I get a Buffer not a string.

Samer is true if a use a FileReader approach

I don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Blob.text() returns a promise object, not a string.

So you have to implement like the following to retrieve a string.

```
blob.text().then((value) => {
  console.log(value); // value is the received text
}, (error) => {
  console.error('error:', error.message);
});
```

Blob
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Promise
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I did, and value is returned as a Buffer not a string

Comment: Can you get a string by adding this code?

var s = String.fromCharCode.apply('', new Uint16Array(value)); // value is a Buffer

Comment: I will give it a shot...